# How to copy array into part of another in Go?

Tags: go

I am new to Go, and would like to copy an array (slice) into part of another. For example, I have a largeArray [1000]byte or something and a smallArray [10]byte and I want the first 10 bytes of largeArray to be equal to the contents of smallArray. I have tried:

```
largeArray[0:10] = smallArray[:]
```

But that doesn't seem to work. Is there a built-in memcpy-like function, or will I just have to write one myself?

Thanks!

Comment: @AnschelSchaffer-Cohen I google'd almost exactly that, and this and a few other like it were listed before the official docs. Also, the docs lack examples to help illustrate how it works (I read the docs first, then came here to finally "get it", and yes, I'm new to Go).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use the [copy](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Appending_and_copying_slices) built-in function.

```
package main

func main() {
    largeArray := make([]byte, 1000)
    smallArray := make([]byte, 10)
    copy(largeArray[0:10], smallArray[:])
}
```

Comment: Nitpicky remark: the `[:]` bit in the copy() call is not necessary.

Comment: Does it have to be a copy? Slices can be a kind of overlay of arrays or other slices. So smallSlice := largeArray[0:10] would be enough.

Comment: @Mue: Yes, the copy is from `smallArray` to `largeArray`. You are copying from `largeArray` to `smallSlice` [sic].

Comment: Isnt't that actually creating two slices, not two arrays?
But I guess the same code works for arrays as well

Comment: To be strictly correct, it would be this for creating those arrays in that example: `var largeArray [1000]byte; var smallArray[10]byte`. Note that as indicated, copy can write to a subsection of a slice or array, and I think you can omit the range index on the array because it's copying into 0-9 index of largeArray, copy only copies as much as is contained in the second, and limited by the length (not capacity, I think) of the first.